# How do I write a negation of these statements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Write the negation of each of the following statements.

1. $\forall$ real numbers $x$, if $x^2 > 1$, then $x > 1$
2. $\forall$ $n \in \Bbb Z$, if $n$ is prime then $n$ is odd or $n = 2$

Currently reviewing for a quiz, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The negation of $\forall$ is $\exists \lnot$...

Comment: The negation of "if $p$, then $q$" is : "$p$ and not $q$".

Comment: The negation of "for all things then blah" is "there exists at least one thing where not blah".  So 1) says for all x^2 >1 then x>1 would negate as "$\exists x $ so that $x^2>1$ but $x\le 1$".  The negation of 2) there is an even prime larger than 2.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are of the form

$$\forall\ x : p(x) \implies q(x)$$

The negation is then

$$\exists\ x : \neg \bigl(p(x) \implies q(x)\bigr)$$

or equivalently

$$\exists\ x : p(x) \land \neg q(x)$$

So for your examples, you'd have

1. $\exists$ a real number $x$ with $x^2 > 1$ and $x \le 1$
2. $\exists$ $n \in \Bbb Z$ where $n$ is prime, but $n$ is not odd and $n \neq 2$

Answer (score 0):

To put it rather crudely:

Note that for "all real numbers" it is sufficient to consider "some real numbers except one (or more)." This is what Mauro was suggesting. For Mauro's other statement, we may negate "if this, then that" with "this and not that".

For example, your first statement is 
$$\forall r\in \mathbb{R}, x^2>1 \implies x>1.$$

Stating this as a sentence, "For all real numbers, if a number squared is bigger than 1, then the number is bigger than 1." Using what I said previously, a negation would be: "There exists a real number such that the number squared is bigger than 1 and the number is equal to or smaller than 1." Putting this back into symbol terminology,
$$\exists r\in \mathbb{R}, x^2>1 \text{ and } x\leq 1.$$